# Intuitive interpretation of open and closed sets in topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

This may be a dumb question, but does anyone have an intuitive interpretation of when the set will be closed and when the set will be open, in the topological spaces?

I am confused especially when I heard that $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is neither an open nor a closed set. To me, I believe a set with a single element x, {x} should be a closed set, because we can also re-write it as [x, x].

I am very new to topology, so I am familiar with little theorems or assumptions in topology.

Thanks!

Comment: A set with a single element ("singleton") is indeed closed (in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$; in other topologies [things can get weirder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space)). However, $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a singleton. So what's the connection?

Comment: I talks about the singleton because $\mathbb{Q}$ is the union of a countably infinite number of singletons.

Comment: Arbitrary unions of closed sets aren't necessarily closed. *Every* set is the union of all its singletons; does that mean that (in the context of $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology) every set is closed? Closedness is only guaranteed to be preserved by *finite* unions. *Openness* is preserved by arbitrary unions.